# Homomorphisms of $\phi: \mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(f) = f(0)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been reading Charles Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra*, and I'm stuck at this exercise (B1 of Chapter 14 on page 142):

> Prove that each of the following is a homomorphism, and describe its kernel:
>
> - The function $\phi: \mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(f) = f(0)$

I understand that to prove that the function $\phi$ is a homomorphism, I need to prove that $\phi(f \circ g) = \phi(f) + \phi(g)$. However, $\phi(f \circ g) = (f \circ g)(0) = f(g(0))$. Then, how do we know that any functions $f$ and $g$ in the set $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies that $f(g(0)) = f(0) + g(0)$?

Given that Pinter's exercises are usually straightforward and are arranged in the order of progressing difficulty, I must have missed something obvious. Is the group $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ not just the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Or the group operations are not just function composition or addition/multiplication? Or the proof depends on how I define the kernel? Any hints how I should proceed?

**Update**
I indeed got the definition of $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ wrong. It is actually defined in page 45 of the book, and is short for $\langle \mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R}), + \rangle$, namely for any function $f,g \in \mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R}), [f + g](x) = f(x) + g(x)$. The proof is straightforward with this definition. I guess this is the culprit of taking too long to read a book in spare time while having a bad memory. :-)

Comment: If the group operation on $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ is addition of real-valued functions, then it certainly is a homomorphism (assuming $\mathbb{R}$ refers to the additive group of reals).  I don't have the book, but you should check to see what Pinter defines $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ to mean

Comment: For the sake of those of us without the book, please define what group $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ is. I suspect doing so will also solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Hayden and carmichael561. The set $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R}$ is short for $\langle \mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R}), + \rangle$, as defined in P45 of the book. The group operator is function addition, not composition.

Comment: @user159566 we don't care of the page number since we won't  read the book, so again define $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ (and with the addition of functions the kernel of $f \mapsto f(0)$ is obvious)

Comment: @user1952009, my bad. I thought the notation was standard. I put the page number there in case those who do have the book may have the same question as I did. The definition of $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all functions $f: R \rightarrow R$, with the operation $+$ for function addition: $\forall f, g \in \mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R}): [f + g](x) = f(x) + g(x) $